# Add variable to end of object function call

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object

I have a object called `story` and a variable called `scene`, i'm trying to make the scene variable add onto the object call. What i mean is instead of

```
myobject.myfunction
```

i want to be able to use

```
myobject.myvariable
```

my variable will link to my function but the variable changes at certain times. Is there a way i can do this, because when i try it adds it as a function call.

Hopefully you understand what i mean but it is quite difficult to explain. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are equivalent:

`o.myFn();`

`o['myFn']();`

So you can do:

`myobject[myvariable]()`